# How to best calculate the sum of a objects' property?

Tags: java

If an object `car` has a property `fuel`, and I have a list of these objects `cars`: how can I best calculate the sum of this property `getCarsFuel()` of all objects in the list?

```
class CarStock {
    List<Car> cars;

    public int getCarsFuel() {
        int result = 0;     

        for (Car car : cars) {
            result += car.getFuel();
        }

        return result;
    }
}

class Car {
    int fuel;
}
```

Are there better ways, or can't it be done less "boilerplate".
I could image something like `sum(List<T> list, String property)` -> `sum(cars, "fuel")`
?

Comment: Sure you could write a helper method such as you suggestion. But there is no built-in way to do this in Java.

Comment: @SamIam: using C# is not always an acceptable solution, you can easily go for Groovy and forget M$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you can use [lambdaj](https://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/), you can write something like:

```
import static ch.lambdaj.Lambda.*;

List<Car> cars = ...;
int result = sumFrom(cars).getFuel();
```

For some more examples of how to use lambdaj, see the [Features](https://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/wiki/LambdajFeatures) page on the lambdaj wiki.

Comment: But there is gross lack of efficacy in this method. Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25343897/gross-lack-of-efficacy-in-using-lambdaj-over-iteration